# StartWebSession cannot start Firefox driver

Tags: automation, web, webdriver

I'm trying to launch a web session using `StartWebSession[]` or `StartWebSession["Firefox", Visible -> True]` using MMA 13.1 on a Windows 10 Enterprise box, but keep getting the error

> Failure: "Unable to start Firefox driver process"

However, I have the latest Firefox version installed and it is running fine.

On the `StartWebSession[]` help page, I cannot find how to query the search path for the Firefox executable or debug the issue. How do I solve this problem?

Thx,
Ron

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, and think it's a good question to understand how to define what is exactly executed by `"Firefox"` (+1).

Comment: On my system v12.2.0-Win7-x64, it started a process object that contained this path: `"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\12.2\\SystemFiles\\Components\\WebUnit\\\
Resources\\DriverBinaries\\GeckoDriver\\Windows-x86-64\\geckodriver.\
exe"`.

Comment: On my PC I get the path to "geckodriver.exe" when I run ``WebUnit`Private`findDriver["Firefox", $SystemID]``. I found this playing with the PrintDefinitions ResourceFunction.

Comment: I get a similar path to geckodriver.exe. When I execute it in a command window, it says it'll be listening to some port and then it's waiting, so it seems geckodriver works. The Mathematica error message doesn't explain any details or debugging options, so how do I move on?